# skipping rows in the jdbc FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it possible to skip some rows in a `FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet`, except calling `ResultSet#next()` several times?

Comment: What's wrong with calling `next()`?

Comment: Fetching unnecessary data, i suppose

Comment: I am trying to avoid the overhead when skipping large amount of rows. Even calling next() can produce significant load for large amount of rows, and I suppose that next() may fetch the data to the client as well, since row data become available after call.
I cannot "fix query" because I don't know query - in this case it's just a String that shall be executed.

Comment: In the first place, fix the query , so that it skips unnecesarry rows.

Comment: @krokodilko did you read previous comments? ))))

Comment: There is no such such feature in JDBC that sends a request to the server "please skip N rows and don't sent them to me over the line". All processing is done an the client side. JDBC driver must fetch data over the line, then your program is able to skip fetched rows. If you want to avoid the overhead and do not want to fetch unwanted data from the server, you **must fix the query**, there is no other way.

Comment: Actually, there is - for scrollable cursors, but it sends data to the client as well...
It's a bit stupid then. Design leak. Ok, I suspected that, thank you for confirmation. And regarding query fixing - please try to understand that it is a bit **difficult to fix ANY unknown query** ))))) It is surely possible but would take a lot of effort )))))

Comment: Are you guys kidding or trolling? )))) i said, i do not know the query, it can be arbitrary))) do you want me to “fix” all queries entered by all admins in every installation of that system? )))))

Comment: We are just point out to you that you don't *really* need to solve this problem at all.  (Which is good, because there isn't a better solution than what you are doing.)  But it is also worth noting that you could get the same answer (No) simply by reading the javadocs for ResultSet, etc.

Comment: It is because you don’t understand the problem ))))

Comment: *"Do you want me to “fix” all queries entered by all admins in every installation of that system?"* - You have a rather unusual system design if you 1) allow admins to roll their own queries and 2) want to skip the first N rows in all resultsets.  Really unusual.  So unusual that it is not surprising that the standard APIs and standard solutions won't work for you.

Comment: The goal is to filter out the data on the server, not on the client, in order to avoid sending the data over the network. If the query cannot be fixed, then maybe it could be "wrapped" in another query like `SELECT * FROM ( my_query ) LIMIT 100,200` ? Or implement some filter using a feature like pipelined function in oracle ? I dont know your application, too few details. But the general idea is: filter the data on the server, not on the client at JDBC side.

Comment: I think we do.  Now that you have actually explained it.  (Compare the information you have provided in the comments with what you wrote in your Question.)

Comment: Stephen, let me tell you one surprising thing - "standard APIs" have this feature for years. ))))) I know it since middle of 90th in informix - it's called "scrollable cursors". And it is quite usual feature even implemented in modern Java )))). But in this case it does not help, because in the jdbc  implementation (at least Oracle) all fetched data for scrollable cursors will anyway be transferred to the client. So, I thought that for FORWARD_ONLY resultsets there's a possibility to move cursor **forward** ))) And please stop posting meaningless comments if you don't know or there's no answer

Comment: Yes, currently I did exactly that - wrapped the source query in another "select from" but it affects the optimizer and creates additional overhead, that's why I asked that. Ok, no solution, it's clear, thank you! )))))

Comment: Stephen, please read the Javadoc and understand that scrollable cursors are part of the jdbc standard )))))

Comment: Come on, guys, it’s a nice question, don’t be offended, why downvote? ))))))

Comment: Umm ... if you put the details that you revealed in the comments into the Question itself, *then* it would be a nice question.  Upvotes / downvotes are to flag whether a Question will be useful to other people.  And that includes whether other people will be able to understand the actual Question with reading a rambling stream of comments.  Use the "edit" button.

Comment: The question is perfectly clear and I don’t really care about these votes, just found it funny )))) i’d likely explained further but have no idea how. It’s a large system that has a part for queries management. It’s supposed to transfer data to clients - whether web or network. Queries may return a lot of data so either client or network wouldn’t be capable to handle. That’s why i tried to send the data by “portions” lets clients decide what row to start from

Comment: If you want scrollable cursors, then don't ask for a TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY result set, but a scrollable one instead. If the server supports scrollable cursors, then the driver will likely use the API that indeed physically does skip rows.

Comment: And, please, stop with the use of closing parentheses in your comments, it is rather annoying and makes your comments harder to use.

Comment: @krokodilko There actually is such a feature in JDBC, it is called [`ResultSet.relative`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#relative-int-), which is not supported for `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` result sets.

Comment: @Mark, I understand that, but I thought that there's a hidden method somewhere I don't know about. Like, to get foreign keys it is necessary to retrieve DatabaseMetaData from Connection. I want to scroll forward, so, why couldn't it be implemented for FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet? Sure, I tried both ResultSet#relative and ResultSet#absoluteon on Oracle 12 and PostgreSql 10 first, got an exception as expected, and asked here then.
This is not parentheses, it's just smiles - wouldn't you agree, it's funny to get such a strange comments, not related to this clear and simple question?  

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to skip some rows in the FORWARD_ONLY ResultSet, except calling ResultSet#next() several times?

No, it is not possible with JDBC APIs.  As you pointed out, scrollable cursors (e.g. `ResultSet::absolute`) don't help on Oracle.  And they are an optional feature anyway.

And also for the [Oracle 10g drivers](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/resltset.htm#i1023588):

> "You cannot position a forward-only result set. Any attempt to position it or to determine the current position will result in a SQLException."

Calling `next()` multiple times is the only portable solution.

- It might be possible with vendor-specific APIs, though you would most likely need to implement your application differently for each backend database.
- It might be possible to implement using some vendor specific "magic" on the server side.
- It *would be* possible to implement this by rewriting the queries, either by hand, or by using some kind of preprocessor.